# Bug with code of conduct notification

Tags: bug, design

Not sure if this is related to the new theme that's being worked on or not, but:

[image]

Comment: Repro'ed on Firefox 61.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Ditto on Firefox 61.0.1 on OS X and Chrome 68.0.3440.84

Comment: Repro'd on Chromium 67.0.3396.99 too.

Comment: Ill be the odd duck then! windows 10 too :D

Comment: Firefox 61.0.1 and Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 too. :D @Rinzwind (If this is not odd enough, I can check on OS X 10.6, Windows XP or even [Windows 2000](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1585352921532642&set=a.161059410628674.42056.100001738485523&type=3). ;-) )

Comment: same thing with Firefox 61.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04